# Update Kendo Grid content after an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am updating a kendo grid datasource content after an ajax call and this is my code

```
 $http
     .get("http://entengcdn.apphb.com/api/user")
     .success(function(r){
         $scope.optUser.dataSource.data = r;
     });
```

i also tried

```
$http
     .get("http://entengcdn.apphb.com/api/user")
     .success(function(r){
         $scope.$apply(function(){
             $scope.optUser.dataSource.data = r;
         });
     });
```

but still not functioning

i prepared a fiddle to see the example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgdagpin/awkoLxrd/3/)

any help would be appreciated.

TIA

Comment: Have you tried this link: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/the-grid-widget#how-to-bind-the-grid-using-the-http-service ?

Comment: Yeah but my scenario is different because all object must be loaded once in ng-init from angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:**

The problem is that you are modifying the options of the grid in your `success` handler but `options` are not an `ObservableObject`, i.e. once initialized, they are not observed for changes. If you want to change your KendoUI `grid` object you need to use something like:

Add to your HTML definition `kendo-grid="grid"` so we can reference the Grid object from `$scope`:

```
<div kendo-grid="grid" kendo-grid k-options="optUser"></div>
```

Now, the Javascript is:

```
$http
    .get("http://entengcdn.apphb.com/api/user")
    .success(function(r){
        // Get reference to grid object
        $scope.grid.dataSource.data(r);
    });
```

Your JSFiddle modified here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/awkoLxrd/6/

**Option 2:**

The other possibility is delaying the creation of the Grid until you actually get the data. You can do it adding to the HTML `k-ng-delay="optUser"`:

```
<div kendo-grid k-options="optUser" k-ng-delay="optUser"></div>
```

And now move the Grid options initialization inside the `success` event handler:

```
$http
    .get("http://entengcdn.apphb.com/api/user")
    .success(function(r){
        $scope.optUser = {
            dataSource: {
                data: r,
                ...
            },
            sortable: true,
            selectable: "single",
            ...
        };        
    });
```

Your JSFiddle modified here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/awkoLxrd/5/

Comment: Oh i see.. Thanks @OnaBai.. I have read about that also and i tried another solution.. What i did is i am waiting for all the widget to load then using your Option 1. I waited for the event kendoRendered to trigger before calling the ajax so the Option 1 is applied

Comment: This is the reference for kendoRendered http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/global-events#kendorendered